# Angular ui-grid not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have an Angular template with a textbox, a button and a ui-grid to display the items added:

```html
<form name="frmNewPlace" ng-submit="newPlace()">
  <div class="sectionTitle">Add a new place</div>
  <div class="contentSection">
    <input type="text" name="placeName" ng-model="dataStoreNewPlace.Name">
    <input type="submit" value="Add place" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="sectionTitle">Existing places</div>
<div class="contentSection">
  <div id="placesGrid" class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
function getPlaces($scope, $http){
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
    {field: 'name', displayName: 'Place Name'}]}

  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/GetPlaces'}).then(function (response) {
  $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
  }, function(response){
    console.log('failed:' + response);
  });
}

scannfeast.controller('placesController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  getPlaces($scope, $http);

  $scope.dataStoreNewPlace = {};
  $scope.newPlace = function(){
  $http.post('/api/NewPlace',   $scope.dataStoreNewPlace).success(function(data){
  getPlaces($scope, $http);});
}

}]);
```

I can see the GET request after I add a new item but the ui-grid doesn't update itself. When I refresh the page the new item is there as expected.

I tried forcing the ui-grid to update using the code below but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.queueGridRefresh();
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
$scope.gridApi.grid.refreshCanvas();
$scope.gridApi.grid.refreshRows();
```

I also tried forcing the ng-view to update using `$apply()` but I get an error saying a digest is already in place.

Any ideas?

Comment: It will be good, if you can create a plucker link and replicate the issue.